# how to model nested object with pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have this small pydantic code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class B:
    a: int


class A(BaseModel):
    b: dict[str, B]


d = {
    "b": {
        "us": {"a": 1},
        "uk": {"a": 2}
    }
}
m = A.parse_obj(d)

print(m.dict())
```

when I run it it shows

```
RuntimeError: no validator found for <class '__main__.B'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

It works, if I rewrite the model as below:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    b: dict[str, dict[str, int]]


d = {
    "b": {
        "us": {"a": 1},
        "uk": {"a": 2}
    }
}
m = A.parse_obj(d)

print(m.dict())
```

But I want to define pydantic models for nested objects as well.

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the definition of `B`:

```
class B(BaseModel):
    a: int
```

Pydantic needs a model definition to define how an input should be parsed into a model instance.

Comment: oh right. sorry I just had missed that